# Issues with reading & decrypting very LARGE files, in bytes, in Java

Tags: java, encryption, io

When reading from a very large encrypted file in Java, I am using the following code:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(saveLocation), "utf-8"));

int read;
byte buffer[] = new byte[16384];
byte getData[] = new byte[16384];

while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
{

 baos.write(buffer, 0, read);

 Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(symCipher);
 IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(initVecBytes);
 cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey, ivParameterSpec);
 byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(baos.toByteArray());
 String s = new String(original);
 writer.append(s);
 baos.reset();
}

writer.close();
```

As the file is very large (too large for me to load into memory in one go) I am reading it into a small buffer, then encrypting the small bytes of data and finally, writing them to a file.

However, when I do this, some of the data looks to be corrupted:

```
</AddressLine><_��SR����_�hEE</AddressLine></AddressLines><Postcode>
```

When **I use a smaller file** that isn't 16k it works fine, I only seem to get small amounts of corrupted data at the start of a new array read, then it's fine again until the next array read, and so on.

Anyone got any idea why this isn't working properly?

Comment: What is `symCipher`?

Comment: Why don't you use streams that are meant for this sort of thing? CipherInputStream and CipherOutputStream come to mind. You could also use the `Cipher#update(byte)` method.

Comment: You need to `.init` once, then run each bufferful except optionally the last through `.update`, then the last (or an empty one) through `.doFinal`, all as described in the javadoc for `Cipher`. Also: writing to `BAOS` and then reading back is a waste of time, both `.update` and `.doFinal` can take an array range; and default-decoding bytes to a `String` and then passing to `Writer` which encodes back to bytes is always costly and only works if the default charset is a complete single-byte code which is not always the case; just write the bytes on the OutputStream instead. ...

Comment: ... Or as @Artjom suggests let `Cipher*Stream` do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because most ciphers are stateful. Specifically, in cipher block chaining mode the plaintext must be XOR-ed with previous cipher text block. But every 16k, you are XORing it with the IV instead. You can't re-initialize the `Cipher` in the middle of a decryption operation.

Here are the five lines of code [to which EJP alluded.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37262271/3474)

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(symCipher);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, originalKey, new IvParameterSpec(initVecBytes));
try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("file.txt"))) {
  Files.copy(new CipherInputStream(in, cipher), Paths.get(saveLocation));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Get rid of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` and the `Writer` and write the decrypted arrays directly to a `FileOutputStream`.
2. Use the same `Cipher` for the whole file, both when encrypting and decrypting, and initialize it once, not once per read.
3. You can do all this in about five lines of code with a `CipherInputStream`.